# How to display different date/time format in textview using hr, day and calender

Tags: android, datetime, kotlin

I am trying to work on displaying dates and I am experiencing a challenge. So I have this one `textview` in my adapter class and I want the time displayed to be in 3 different format, Say for instance when its past 24hrs say date e.g `Saturday` if its very old just display date `02/9/2021` and if a day has not ended just display time `12:00am` my problem is how do I achieve this on Android using Kotlin? here is a sample image I got

Comment: I would save everything in simple date format.

Not having the hours on the other dates in the meantime it doesn't make much sense to save the hours, where there are the hours just put today's date.
For those with the day of the week I would do a loop backwards, starting from today's date and as soon as the day of the week coincides I would exit the loop with the date.
While where you have the date, leave it like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple just get difference between now and your date and use SimpleDateFormat to formate date

```
 fun getDate(date:Long){
    val nowCal = Calendar.getInstance()
    val dateCal = Calendar.getInstance().apply {
        //just for test, replace with your date timestamp
        timeInMillis += TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(9)
    }

    val nowDay = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(nowCal.timeInMillis)
    val dateDay = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(dateCal.timeInMillis)

    when {
        (dateDay - nowDay) <= 1L -> {
            val formatter = SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a")
            val dateStr = formatter.format(dateCal.time)
            println(dateStr)
        }

        (dateDay - nowDay) <= 6L -> {
            val dateStr = dateCal.getDisplayName(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.LONG, Locale.ENGLISH)
            println(dateStr)
        }

        else ->{
            val formatter = SimpleDateFormat("M/d/yy")
            val dateStr = formatter.format(dateCal.time)
            println(dateStr)
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: I noticed however since I have one textview it's changing the time for every new entry. What would you do in that case?